# How to stop player from walking on walls

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm building a test avatar chat... thingy in ActionScript3, but I've come across a problem, whenever I click the chatbar to say something, my avatar (which is currently a penguin) walks to it -- how can I prevent this from happening? In other words, how do I build a wall and keep the penguins out?

This is the code I'm using to make my penguin move.

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, myClickReaction);  
// speeds ALONG NYPOTENUSE  
var v:Number = 7;  
// vector of movement  
var dir:int = 100;  
// mouse click point  
var clickPoint:Point = new Point();  
// angle doesn't change metween clicks - so it can be global  
var angle:Number;  

function myClickReaction (e:MouseEvent):void {   
     clickPoint = new Point(mouseX, mouseY);  
     angle = Math.atan2(clickPoint.y - penguin.y, clickPoint.x - penguin.x);  
     dir = angle >= 0 ? -1 : 1;  
     addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);  
}  

function onEnterFrame(e:Event):void {  
     var projectedX:Number = penguin.x + v * Math.cos(angle);  
     var projectedY:Number = penguin.y + v * Math.sin(angle);  
     var diff:Number = clickPoint.y - projectedY;  
     if (diff / Math.abs(diff) == dir) {  
          penguin.x = clickPoint.x;  
          penguin.y = clickPoint.y;  
          removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);  
     }  
     else {  
          penguin.x = projectedX;  
          penguin.y = projectedY;  
     }  
}
```

Comment: **DisplayObject.hitTestObject(...)** to detect collisions between two display objects ( https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#hitTestObject() ) or maybe a simple **if..else** block that does not allow coordinates to cross certain limits.

Comment: Hi, could you walk me through it? I'm a little slow.

Comment: Okay, so I've worked out the whole DisplayObject and hitTestObject but I'm still unsure on how to block it from reaching it.

Comment: Save current coordinates > move > hit test > roll back if positive.

Comment: Okay, now I've got an issue where my player basically ping-pongs to the area. It's pushed back to it's previous location but keeps trying to get there. Any suggestions?

Comment: Cancel the movement upon hitting the wall, no?

Comment: I've managed to stop the player from spazzing around by using "penguin.y+= 1;", but the player can still access the area, before slowly sliding back outside the area.

Comment: That's not cancelling the movement. Just unsubscribe from ENTER_FRAME event just like you do once the avatar reaches the destination.

Comment: I don't have a balanced funny/sarcastic answer to this so I'll just say I'm glad you've finally made it through.

Comment: Hi. Me Again. Slight problem. Although it does work, very successfully I might add, it always disables the player whenever a player may accidentally move their mouse there. Is it possible to activate it only if the player clicks it, and not just hovers over it? Many thanks xxx

Comment: It shouldn't, actually. The code clearly shows that only CLICK event triggers the motion.

Comment: The code I've used is "function hitTest(e:Event) {
 if(player_dest.hitTestObject(mc_wall)){
              removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);  
 }" player_dest is a movieclip that follows the mouse.